# Which is the fastest way to search elements in the dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

Performance is really important for my app so I was wondering which is the fastest way to get an element of the DOM in order to change its text?

Is jQuery faster than `document.getElementByClass` or `document.getElementById`? or is there any other tool or framework that is faster to do the job?

Comment: jQuery *uses* `getElemntById` and other native methods. jQuery will never be faster, comparing apples to apples.

Comment: There is no framework that is faster than native javascript. If you want to check any specific cases I would recommened using [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/).

Comment: having said that.. the point of jQuery is to also make things cross-browser compatible. So if that is a concern for you, by the time you write "native" code to account for all that, you aren't going to end up with much less than jQuery or the like.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to access an element will be to use a variable which keeps reference to it...

On the second place I would put `document.getElementById`, browsers should use something like a dictionary/hash map behind the scene so the access to element with given ID is with complexity `O(1)`.

Definitely jQuery's Sizzle will work a bit slower that Vanilla JS.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` and Sizzle are not fully comparable. QSA has a quirk with finding descendants that you wouldn't expect, and jQuery/sizzle "handle it". And Sizzle supports many selectors that QSA does not

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` is the fastest. But also, if you plan to reuse found object multiple times - cache it in a variable so you don't have to look it up again. There's more to speed than lookup methods.